# How to Encrypt and Decrypt column values use it in both nativeQueries and JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, encryption

I need to encrypt values in a MySQL database table :

user

```
| userId |      email   | userAge | firstName| lastName  | userType |
|--------|--------------|---------|-----------|----------|--------- |
|    1   |john@gmail.com| 20      | John      | Smith    | 1        |
```

My user class as following

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "user")
 public class User{

 @Id @GeneratedValue
 @Column(name = "userId ")
 private int userId;
 
 @Column(name = "firstName")
 private String firstName;
 
 @Column(name = "email")
 private String email;
 
 @Column(name = "lastName")
 private String lastName;

 @Column(name = "userType ")
 private String userType ;

 // getters and setters
 }
```

I tried to do this by using AttributeConverter

```
@Component
public class ValueAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {

private static final String AES = "AES";
private static final String SECRET = "secretkey";

private final Key key;
private final Cipher cipher;

public AttributeEncryptor() throws Exception {
    key = new SecretKeySpec(SECRET.getBytes(), AES);
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES);
}

@Override
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String value) {
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
                                                                                
   return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes()));
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | InvalidKeyException e) 
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
      }
     }

@Override
public String convertToEntityAttribute(String value) {
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(value)));
    } catch (InvalidKeyException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e{
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
      }
      }     
      }
```

And added @Convert annotation to the attribute

```
@Column
@Convert(converter = ValueAttributeConverter.class)
private String email;
```

This will encrypt the column values.

But the problem is I have native queries that I use in my UserRepository

```
 @Query(nativeQuery = true , value = "select * from users where email=?1 
  and 
 firstName =?2")
```

In this case, it is not working since the email value is encrypted. If I use other columns rather than email such as lastName. It is working and returns the decrypted value.

I tried to encrypt the string before suing it in the query

```
 email = valueAttributeConverter.convertToEntityAttribute(email);
```

It works but I don't know if this approach is good.

I also tried using @ColumnTransformer

```
  @Column
  @ColumnTransformer(
      read = "cast(aes_decrypt(email, 'secretkey') as char(255))", 
      write = "aes_encrypt(?, 'secretkey')"
       ) 
     private String email;
```

This is also working fine when encrypting but won't work when I need to decrypt.
Even if I select using another column

```
 @Query(nativeQuery = true , value = "select * from users where userId 
   =?1")
```

It doesn't decrypt the value, it returns the encrypted value.

My question is are there any better approaches that I could take to resolve this encrypt and decrypt issue and also use it in both JPA and nativeQuery ?

Comment: If the encryption key is sitting in plaintext in the source code, then a hacker only need find your source code or any backup of it.  Think about this.

Comment: Your `ValueAttributeConverter` is not thread-safe. You should fix that.

Comment: I think you're better off doing the encrypt/decrypt explicitly and exactly when you need it in code rather than try to do everything with annotations.

Comment: Your problem will probably be resolved by getting rid of native query. Since you already have entity class for user table, why not use `JPQL` instead of native query?

Comment: Your `@ColumnTransformer` is good, in navtive sql query you have to write decryptor during select

Comment: @silentsudo The problem with @ ColumnTransformer is that it will again encrypting the already encrypted value on savaAll () call. Do you know any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should rethink using native queries in your code. You could take a look into using the *Data Access Object* pattern: https://www.baeldung.com/java-dao-pattern

Using native queries should be a last resort and used only in cases where you absolutely need some platform specific feature.

Architecturally you could keep your User entity as it is, but substitute the native query for a [JPQL](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select) query in your Data Access Object, for example your native query example

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true , value = "select * from users where userId =?1")
```

would be transformed to a DAO method:

```java
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

public class UserDao implements Dao<User> {
    
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    // standard constructors
    
    @Override
    public List<User> findByEmail(String plaintextEmail) {
        String encryptedEmail = myEncryptionMethod(plaintextEmail);
        
        TypedQuery<User> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email = :email", User.class);
        return query.setParameter("email", encryptedEmail).getResultList();
    }
    
    // ... other DAO methods like getById, update, delete, ...
    
}
```

The DAO pattern allows you to create arbitrarily complex queries with business logic (like in your case) and gives you more control.
JPA should handle the encrypted values automatically in the returned User object if you use the AttributeConverter from your example.

The nice thing about JPQL is that it is not native SQL and it is interpreted by JPA before generating platform specific queries automatically. Your code would work on any DB backend supported by JPA. Also, you get security benefits like SQL injection protection for free.

Answer (score 1):

• Use the `@AttributeConverter` (fixing thread-safety issues. This is do not use `Cipher` and `Key` as class level attributes)

• Use only JPQL. As long as you stick to JPQL all the encryption/decryption will happen magically

• If you explicitly need a native query (which you should't in basic use cases as the one you are exposing) you need to encryp/decrypt manually always. In which case I would recomend using a `@Stateless` bean that exposes methods to encrypt/decrypt. You can inject it in the AttributeConverter and wherever you need to manually encrypt/decrypt.